# Update multi nested array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a document schema in Mongodb that looks like this:

```
{
    _id: 1
    tags: [{
        tag: 'foo'
        links: [{
            link: 'http:www.google.com'
            date: '123'
        }] 
    }]
}
```

I am trying to push a link into the 'links' array that will be unique to the document.

My first query...

```
db.userlinks.update (
    {_id: 1, tags: {$nin: [{tag:'foo'}]}}, 
    {$push: {'tags': {tag:'foo'}}}, 
    {upsert: true}
)
```

Gives me this (creates the tag if it doesn't exist)

```
{ "_id" : 1, "tags" : [ { "tag" : "foo" } ] }
```

I then follow that up with this query...

```
db.userlinks.update (
    {_id: 1, tags: {tag: 'foo', links: {$nin: [{link: 'http://www.google.com'}]}}}, 
    {$push: {tags: {tag: 'foo', links: {link: 'http://www.google.com', date: '123'}}}}, 
    {upsert: true}
)
```

But I get this error: "Cannot apply $push/$pushAll modifier to non-array"

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the 'update' component of my second query, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated.

## EDIT

My first query is now... (thanks to Joe)

```
db.userlinks.update (
    {_id: 1, tags: {$nin: [{tag:'foo'}]}}, 
    {$push: {'tags': {tag:'foo', links:[]}}}, 
    {upsert: true}
)
```

My second query is now...

```
db.userlinks.update (
    {_id: 1, 'tags.tag': 'foo'}, 
    {$push: {'tags.$.links': {link: 'http://www.google.com', date: '123'} } }
)
```

Which successfully pushes the link into the 'links' array, however it also allows duplicates.  I can't allow duplicate links.  $addToSet kind of works, however if the date changes, then it still inserts a duplicate link.

Is there a way to either check for the existence of the link in the 'query' part of my second query, or instead only addToSet if certain fields match?

Comment: you can't.  consider changing your schema?

Comment: I don't particularly want to change my schema, because this is modeled exactly the way it's output which means I don't have to do any data wrangling once I've got it out of the db.  I thought that was supposed to be the main reason for using Mongodb actually?  The ability to model your objects directly into and out of the database.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I finally got it...  although if anyone can see a better way to do this, please add it as an answer.

```
// create the userlinks collection if it doesn't exist
// also add a tag 'foo' into it, but only if the tag doesn't exist
db.userlinks.update (
    {_id: '1', 'tags.tag': {$nin: ['foo']}}, 
    {$push: {'tags': {tag:'foo', links:[]}}},
    {upsert: true}
)

// add a link into the 'foo' tag, but only if the link doesn't exist
db.userlinks.update(
    {_id: '1', 'tags.tag': 'foo', 'tags.links.link': {$nin: ['http://foobar.com']}},
    {$push: {'tags.$.links': {link: 'http://foobar.com', date: '15'} } }
)
```

Comment: @Harley : How can we update date to 20 if We know the _id , 'tags.tags' and 'tags.links.link'...db.doc.update({_id : , 'tags.tags : , 'tags.links.link':  },{$inc : {'tags.links.$.date' : 20}}) is not working as we have two arrays..Please Help

Comment: Sorry Praveen, I haven't worked with Mongo since I made this post and I've basically forgotten the intricacies of the query language I'm afraid.  Perhaps open a new question?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps change your first query to:

```
db.userlinks.update (
    {_id: 1, tags: {$nin: [{tag:'foo'}]}}, 
    {$push: {'tags': {tag:'foo', links:[]}}}, 
    {upsert: true}
)
```

The $push operation should only affect links, not the tag.

```
{$push: {'tags.links': {link: 'http://www.google.com', date: '123'} } },
```

Comment: That initiated the 'links' to an empty array, which is good and probably something I needed, however my second query still raises the same error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have the same error using this as the second query:db.userlinks.update (
    {_id: 1, tags: {tag: 'foo', links: {$nin: [{link: 'google.com'}]}}}, 
    {$push: {'tags.links': {link: 'google.com', date: '123'} } },
    {upsert: true}
)