# Pushing data into nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Whats the best way of pushing data into an array that's nested several levels deep in arrays...

Here's an example document ( made up ) that's representative of the data in the document, except the real document has more schools with more classes and more students. Each 'thing' has a unique id :-

```
{
  _id: 4353467865,
  school : [
     { 
       _id: 3425353,
       name: 'school of rock',
       class: [
           {
           _id: 3242342
           name: 'Room1',
           students: [
             { _id: 345456562, name: 'Kevin' }
           ]
           },
           {
             // more classes with more students nested underneath
           }
       ]
     },
     {
       // more schools, classes, students...
     }
  ]
}
```

Now I know the id of the document, school and class,  and now I want to do an update $push into the students array a `{_id: 234554363, name: 'Barry'}` for that class.

How do I construct an update query for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question since I've been using Mongo for a while now.

first answer...

When designing Mongo stuff, I was super paranoid to try and get things in one doc if I could since that's the whole benefit. Reality is you don't have to be too paranoid.  School and Class could be separate collections. It does depend a bit on how you are using them, but for the most I would do separate collections these days.

second answer...

I have needed to do nested arrays, however any level of nesting array can be separated out into non nested arrays with keys which is then trivial to update using mongo

so

```
school : [
 { 
  _id: 3425353,
   name: 'school of rock',
 }
],
classes: [
           {           
           _id: 3242342
           school_id: 3425353,
           name: 'Room1',
           }
],
students: [
             { _id: 345456562, class_id: 3242342, name: 'Kevin' }
             { _id: 345456563, class_id: 3242342, name: 'Gilbert' }
          ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the below 2 links solve your problem?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#nested-arrays

[Update multi nested array in Mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003258/update-multi-nested-array-in-mongodb)

Comment: nope.  That allows a single level of nesting,  it doesn't allow for easy access to deeper nesting