# Add item to an array which is a subdocument

Tags: mongodb

I have this document in the collection 'disciplines':

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54db5298a59d60df0018525c"),
    "disciplineId" : 61,
    "title" : "Pipes",
    "mainCategories" : [ 
        {
            "title" : "Shut valves",
            "_id" : ObjectId("54db5298a59d60df0018527a"),
            "subCategories" : [ 
                {                        
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54db5298a59d60df0018527c"),
                    "title" : "Two-part valves",
                    "typeComponents" : []
                }, 
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("54db5298a59d60df0018527b"),
                    "title" : "Three-part valves",
                    "typeComponents" : []
                }
       }
   ]
```

I need a query that adds items to typeComponents. Probably a `update` with a `$push` somehow. I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update multi nested array in Mongodb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003258/update-multi-nested-array-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Good question. MongoDB currently can't use two references in an update. I don't know how to do it with you schema... but do you really need that schema?

If you know the categories name, you might model your document like this:

```
db.test.insert({
    "_id" : ObjectId("54db5298a59d60df0018525c"),
    "disciplineId" : 61,
    "title" : "Pipes",
    "mainCategories" : {
        "Shut_valves" : {
            "attribute1": "value1",
            "attribute2": "value2",
            "subCategories" : [ 
                {                        
                    "title" : "Two-part valves",
                    "typeComponents" : []
                }, 
                {
                    "title" : "Three-part valves",
                    "typeComponents" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

You can update your typeComponents array easily with:

```
db.test.update(
{"mainCategories.Shut_valves.subCategories.title":"Two-part valves"},
{$push:{"mainCategories.Shut_valves.subCategories.$.typeComponents": "hello"}})
```